# Set binding for sub controls on parent "proxy" property

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

In a UserControl I have an ItemsControl with a DataTemplate that uses a second control type for the individual items. The main control has a number of DependencyProperties that are mostly passed on to the sub control via the DataTemplate or `RelativeSource` bindings in the sub control's own XAML.

That does not work, however, when I want to use the main control to "proxy" a binding that uses a ValueConverter; i.e.:

Both controls have a property "Stroke" of type `Brush`. In the DataTemplate, the sub control's property is bound to that of the main control:

```
Stroke="{Binding ElementName=RingControl, Path=Stroke}"
```

On the `Stroke` property of the main control, a binding with a ValueConverter is registered that is actually intended to be used by the sub controls. What apparently happens (and I kind of understand that) is that the ValueConverter binding is evaluated only on the main control, and the binding given above only passes the **result** on to the sub controls, while the actual purpose is to apply the value converter to each bound item and set the respective sub control's property accordingly.

How can I set a binding on the main control (because that is the API for the whole thing) and have it passed on to and fully evaluated on each sub control?

(If more context is helpful: The actual project is at https://github.com/TeaDrivenDev/Kiltse/tree/develop/src/TeaDriven.Kiltse [without the `Stroke` properties]; the main control is `Ring`, the sub control is `Arc`. `Trial.fsx` in the test project can be used to test it without needing an application.)

So, I guess what I'm looking for is some kind of meta-binding; a binding for a binding; a "binding delegate" of sorts.

Comment: To whoever voted to close this question has definitely not read the question...